# how do i center my texts and icons in my navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clone apple's site and my text and icons in the navbar are in different positions. I'm practicing with html css and sometimes these kinds of errors frustrate me, so I believe it would be better to consult you.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-links ul{
    display: flex;
}

#nav-bar{
    background-color: #161617ff;
}a

.nav-links ul li a{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: lightgray;
    padding: 0px 9px;
}

svg{
    fill: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
        <div class="nav-links">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <svg height="44" viewBox="0 0 14 44" width="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                                d="m13.0729 17.6825a3.61 3.61 0 0 0 -1.7248 3.0365 3.5132 3.5132 0 0 0 2.1379 3.2223 8.394 8.394 0 0 1 -1.0948 2.2618c-.6816.9812-1.3943 1.9623-2.4787 1.9623s-1.3633-.63-2.613-.63c-1.2187 0-1.6525.6507-2.644.6507s-1.6834-.9089-2.4787-2.0243a9.7842 9.7842 0 0 1 -1.6628-5.2776c0-3.0984 2.014-4.7405 3.9969-4.7405 1.0535 0 1.9314.6919 2.5924.6919.63 0 1.6112-.7333 2.8092-.7333a3.7579 3.7579 0 0 1 3.1604 1.5802zm-3.7284-2.8918a3.5615 3.5615 0 0 0 .8469-2.22 1.5353 1.5353 0 0 0 -.031-.32 3.5686 3.5686 0 0 0 -2.3445 1.2084 3.4629 3.4629 0 0 0 -.8779 2.1585 1.419 1.419 0 0 0 .031.2892 1.19 1.19 0 0 0 .2169.0207 3.0935 3.0935 0 0 0 2.1586-1.1368z">
                            </path>
                        </svg></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Store</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mac</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">iPad</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">iPhone</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Watch</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">AirPods</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tv ve Ev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Eğlence</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Aksesuarlar</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Destek</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="globalnav-image-regular"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15px"
                                height="44px" viewBox="0 0 15 44">
                                <path
                                    d="M14.298,27.202l-3.87-3.87c0.701-0.929,1.122-2.081,1.122-3.332c0-3.06-2.489-5.55-5.55-5.55c-3.06,0-5.55,2.49-5.55,5.55 c0,3.061,2.49,5.55,5.55,5.55c1.251,0,2.403-0.421,3.332-1.122l3.87,3.87c0.151,0.151,0.35,0.228,0.548,0.228 s0.396-0.076,0.548-0.228C14.601,27.995,14.601,27.505,14.298,27.202z M1.55,20c0-2.454,1.997-4.45,4.45-4.45 c2.454,0,4.45,1.997,4.45,4.45S8.454,24.45,6,24.45C3.546,24.45,1.55,22.454,1.55,20z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="globalnav-image-regular"><svg height="44" viewBox="0 0 14 44" width="14"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path
                                    d="m11.3535 16.0283h-1.0205a3.4229 3.4229 0 0 0 -3.333-2.9648 3.4229 3.4229 0 0 0 -3.333 2.9648h-1.02a2.1184 2.1184 0 0 0 -2.117 2.1162v7.7155a2.1186 2.1186 0 0 0 2.1162 2.1167h8.707a2.1186 2.1186 0 0 0 2.1168-2.1167v-7.7155a2.1184 2.1184 0 0 0 -2.1165-2.1162zm-4.3535-1.8652a2.3169 2.3169 0 0 1 2.2222 1.8652h-4.4444a2.3169 2.3169 0 0 1 2.2222-1.8652zm5.37 11.6969a1.0182 1.0182 0 0 1 -1.0166 1.0171h-8.7069a1.0182 1.0182 0 0 1 -1.0165-1.0171v-7.7155a1.0178 1.0178 0 0 1 1.0166-1.0166h8.707a1.0178 1.0178 0 0 1 1.0164 1.0166z">
                                </path>
                        </svg></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

please help me

I gave display flex and said align items center but it didn't work

Comment: add `justify-content: center;`  property in `.nav-links ul`

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code to my VSCode and I figured out that you have to add this to the class:

```
nav-links ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
```

}